# exec-maven-plugin javassist load class from dependency

Tags: java, maven, javassist

I have pom.xml file defined as following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>entities</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>entities</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>mydependency</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build> 
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>FirstGenerator</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.mydomain.entities.util.FirstGenerator</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>SecondGenerator</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                    <mainClass>com.mydomain.entities.util.SecondGenerator</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}</argument>
                        <argument>${project.basedir}\..\libraries\mydependency\target\classes</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

During build, it calls two generators, FirstGenerator and SecondGenerator.

SecondGenerator's main method calls another static method with following lines:

```
ClassnameEncoder cne = new ClassnameEncoder();

CtClass CLASSNAMEENCODER = CP.get("com.mydomain.mydependency.serialization.encoder.ClassnameEncoder");
```

When I call this method from TestNG, it works fine.

But when I try maven build (mvn clean install), it throws following exception:

```
javassist.NotFoundException: com.mydomain.mydependency.serialization.encoder.ClassnameEncoder
        at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:450)
```

So, class loader manages to load ClassnameEncoder class from different project which is dependency, and make an instance of it, but in next line, javassist fails to find the same class.

I tried to add dependency to plugin, to change goal, to adjust classpath, but I wasn't able to resolve this problem. Does anybody knows what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Javassist in its default ClassPool loads only classpath given with -cp or through CLASSPATH environment variable. By looking at exec-maven-plugin source code this is not the case (https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecJavaMojo.java).
The main class is being executed in the same JVM:

```
try {
  Class<?> bootClass = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass( bootClassName );
                    
  MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();

  MethodHandle mainHandle = lookup.findStatic(bootClass, "main", MethodType.methodType( void.class, String[].class ) );
                    
  mainHandle.invoke( arguments );
 } catch (...) { ...}
```

The solution is to expand the ClassPool with the classes from current class loader:

```
ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();    
classPool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(this.getClass().getClassLoader()));
```